# Is there a recommended approach to share state between screens in Blend 4 Sketchflow?

Tags: silverlight, expression-blend, sketchflow

I am developing a Sketchflow prototype in Blend 4 and I need to share some state across the entire app - for instance - the currently selected item on screen 1. I looked at using a Datastore but it can only store simple types (strings, booleans,etc.) I want to store an entire object in there and then databind to it from other screens.

I didn't want to have to resort to a shared viewmodel if I didn't have to - it is a throw away prototype and didn't want to start architecting it like a real app.

Any ideas of exisitng facilities in Sketchflow that make this easy?

thanks
Michael

Comment: This question looks very close to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490217/how-can-you-store-state-between-screens-in-sketchflow

Answer (score 0):

The datastore is probably the simplest, but there are other relatively simple, throw away style things you can do.

1. Static variables in your app.xaml.cs files
2. Write your own behavior that has static variables to store global state